# Where should I put try/except?

Tags: python, exception, pandas

In an effort to improve my coding, I was wondering if I should put try/except inside a function or keep it outside. The following examples display what I mean.

```
    import pandas as pd

    df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

    # Example 1
    def do_something(df):
        # Add some columns
        # Split columns
        return df

    try:
        df = do_something(df)
    except Exception, e:
        print e

    # Example 2
    def do_something(df):
        try:
            # Add some columns
            # Split columns
        except Exception, e:
            print e
            df = pd.DataFrame()
        return df

    df = do_something(df)
```

It might seem  the same, but the first example is more clear on what happens while the second seems cleaner.

Answer (score 5):

### Possibility of internal handling

If the function can provide a *sensible* recovery from the exception and handle it within its scope of responsibilities and without any additional information, then you can catch the exception right there

### Raise or translate to caller

Otherwise, it might be better left up to the caller to deal with it. And sometimes even in this case, the function might catch the exception and then immediately raise it again with a translation that makes sense to the caller

Answer (score 4):

It has nothing to do with how it looks, it has to do with where can you handle the exception.

If the exception can be handled inside the function - use it there. If it can't - use it outside the function.

As an example:

```
def pi():
    try:
        return get_awsome_pi_value_from_internetz()
    except NoInternetzError:
        # recover
        return 3.14
```

Or an example where the error can't be handled:

```
def get_square_root(x):
    return x ** 0.5
```

Elsewhere in code:

```
try:
    get_square_root(-1) # imagine -1 was received from user
except ValueError:
    print("Can't find a sensible root for value.")
    # recover / panic
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, You would use `try/except` if you anticipate a potential exception of a specific type. If you catch the exception, your application can continue running while you handle the exception in code. For example:

```
try:
    user = User.objects.get(pk=id)
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    print("could not find user")
```

If you did not wrap that in a try except block, it would throw an exception because the user does not exist. This also saves you from having to call the db to check if the user exists before trying to get him.

There are a lot of built-in [exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html) to python itself. You can define your own by subclassing the Exception class.

Pandas also has a good set of pre-defined [exceptions](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/wiki/Choosing-Exceptions-to-Raise) to catch.

Django also has a set of [exceptions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/exceptions/) (I am using one in my example)

It does not matter what you wrap, as long as you deal with the individual exceptions. You can catch them generally, but then you are not wholly sure as to which exception is being thrown.